# inaccessible due to protection level in MVVM

Tags: swift

I am trying to implement the `MVVM` design pattern; however, I wonder how to resolve the following issue - inaccesible due to protection level.

I should keep the VM properties as `private`; then how to resolve the issue?

**ClassRoomViewController**

```
class ClassRoomViewController: UIViewController, ClassCheckObserver {
  private let classroomVM = ClassRoomViewModel()
    
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // inaccessible due to protection level
    classroomVM.classCheckManager.addObserver(observer: self)
  }
}
```

**ClassRoomViewModel**

```
final class ClassRoomViewModel {
  private let classCheckManager: ClassCheckManager

  init(classCheckManager: ClassCheckManager = .shared) {
    self.classCheckManager = classCheckManager
  }
}
```

Comment: Add wrapper method(s) to your VM perhaps that access the private property. But why does it have to be private?

Comment: could you please elaborate the wrapper method(s) ?

Comment: `func addClassCheckObserver(observer: ClassCheckObserver) { self.classCheckManager.addObserver(observer: observer) }`

Comment: Are you adding this method in `ViewModel`? How do you call it in the `ViewController`?